# AngularJS: $http.post gives 404 error, but $http.get request to the same file is ok

Tags: angularjs, post, get, request, http-status-code-404

I have a problem when trying to push some object into json file on the server side (simple json-server). When I $http.get information from this file everything is ok and I get needed infromation. Then I want user to fill some input field, build object based on user's input and then I want to push this object to my json file. I am trying to create $http.post request, but it returns 404 error (POST http://localhost:3000/employees.json 404 (Not Found)). Can somebody help me, please, and tell what I did wrong?

My code:

```
$scope.employList = [];
$scope.id;

$http.get("employees.json").then(function(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < response.data["Employees"].length; i++) {
    $scope.employList.push(response.data["Employees"][i]);
  };
});

$scope.getId = function() {
  $scope.id = $scope.employList[$scope.employList.length-1].Id;
};

$scope.save = function (name, surname, position) {
  $scope.getId();
  var newObj = {
    "Id": $scope.id + 1,
    "firstName": name,
    "secondName": surname,
    "position": position
  };
  $http.post("employees.json", JSON.stringify(newObj)).then(function (item) {
    employList.push(item);
  });
};
```

I'm using AngularJS and have the following branch structure:
[Branch structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAe3l.png)

Thanks for helping!

-----UPDATE-----

This is my employees.json file:

```js
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "firstName": "Jack",
      "secondName": "Sparrow",
      "position": "Captain"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "firstName": "Michael",
      "secondName": "Jackson",
      "position": "Singer"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "firstName": "Lionel",
      "secondName": "Messi",
      "position": "Footballer"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "firstName": "Steve",
      "secondName": "Jobs",
      "position": "Developer"
    },
    {
      "Id": 4,
      "firstName": "John",
      "secondName": "Smith",
      "position": "Developer"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong in your backend. Please add some backend codes

Comment: I have no backend code, I'm only using json-server: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: It is very strange for me that GET request to the same file works fine, but POST request - fails.

Comment: Well, json-server is your backend so.

Comment: But what can be wrong with it? It is working fine and many people use it. Maybe there is something wrong with my directory branches structure, so that json-server is not able to find needed file? But why then GET request works good?

Comment: I think your post data is in the wrong format. Please add the object you are posting. -> Documentation says: `A POST, PUT or PATCH request should include a Content-Type: application/json header to use the JSON in the request body. Otherwise it will result in a 200 OK but without changes being made to the data.`

Comment: `var newObj = {
    "Id": $scope.id + 1,
    "firstName": name,
    "secondName": surname,
    "position": position
  };`

The same object I'm posting is in the body of my initial question above.

Comment: I think this is not the problem, because:
1. I already tried to modify my request and include a Content-Type: application/json header. Nothing have changed.
2. I get 404 Not Found error, but not as said in documentation: `Otherwise it will result in a 200 OK but without changes being made to the data`

Comment: Maybe this screenshot from command line with started json-server will help to figure out what is going on?  ---> [Command line window][2]
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjbIX.png

Comment: Stupid question but .. have you started your server? CLI command: `node server.js`? Well, I guess yes. The Screenshot shows your CLI output.

Comment: Yes, of course I started it, you can see all requests server handle from the previous screenshot I showed. But to start json-server, as Documentation describes,we need another CLI command: `json-server --watch db.json`
In my case, I use command: `json-server --watch users.json`

Comment: can you add the server code as well

Comment: I have no server code at all.. Or you want me to add content of my employees.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I figure out what was wrong. The problem was in my directory structure which I attach on screenshot. Json-server maintain only one main active file, which can obtain non-GET requests. So I needed to remove my employees.json file and cut and paste all information to users.json file. Then all works fine. Also I renamed users.json to db.json for convinience. All other files should be located at `/public` directory.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$http.post("employees.json",newObj)
     .then(function (response) { 
        employList.push(response.data); 
      });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help me.. The same error. The piece of code I used according to your advice: 
`$http({method: 'POST',
    url: "employees.json",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: newObj}).then(function (response) {
      employList.push(response.data);
    });`

Comment: This wouldn't work also. But eventually I figure out what was wrong. The problem was in my directory structure which I attach on screenshot. Json-server maintain only one main active file, which can obtain non-GET requests. So I needed to remove my employees.json file and cut and paste all information to users.json file. Then all works fine. Also I renamed users.json to db.json for convinience.

Comment: Thanks all for helping!